# Draw an object and update it's position on a panel without flickering

Tags: c#

I want to avoid the flickering, and I also don't want to use a timer. Is there a method for when the form updates or when the graphics get refreshed that I can use instead of a timer?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.LightGray, 3);
        Graphics g;  
        int xpos;
        int ypos;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;  
        }    
        void Draw(string Shape, int x, int y)
        {
            panel1.Invalidate();
            switch (Shape)
            {
                case "Circle":
                    g.FillEllipse(sb, x, y, 20, 20);
                    g.DrawEllipse(p, x, y, 20, 20);
                    break;
            }  
        }
        private void tmrAnimaion_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            xpos += 2;
            Draw("Circle", xpos, ypos);
            if (xpos >= 700)
            {
                xpos = 0;
                ypos += 20;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a timer?

Comment: purely because I would assume there is a more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just draw in Paint or OnPaint()?

[C# WinForms - Paint method questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195459/c-sharp-winforms-paint-method-questions)

[Best practice for custom control painting in Winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718202/best-practice-for-custom-control-painting-in-winforms)

[WinForms paint cycle documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764508/winforms-paint-cycle-documentation)

Comment: yes you can, thanks :), but it still flickers quite horribly. Also, how would you control the rate at which the object moves on different computers if the paint event happens less frequently or more?